# Does any Looney Tunes character ever use any fictional brand-name product that isn't ACME?

Tags: looney-tunes

Now that [Looney Tunes is on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12319/is-bugs-bunny-as-a-whole-on-topic), maybe I can get an answer for something I've been wondering about for a while: Looney Tunes characters, (most famously Wile E. Coyote), always use products with the brand name ACME:
[image: Acme triplestrength fortified leg muscle vitamins; Fleet-foot jet-propelled tennis shoes; one acme do-it yourself tornado kit "Seed your own tornados"; acme dehydrated boulders just add water; acme disintegrating pistol; one acme bat-man's outfit; one acme out-board motor (and one jim-dandy wagon)]
Do they ever use products anywhere from a different fictional company?

Comment: Note: your second picture already includes a non-ACME product

Comment: Has the "Jim Dandy" wagon in the last image also been overlooked?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I think "jim-dandy" might be an adjective. Not one you'd hear in past 30 years, though.

Comment: Presumably you're excluding Space Jam which features many Looney Tunes characters interacting with real-world brands

Comment: @Valorum I clearly state "fictional" in the question.

Comment: @AbrahamRay there used to be a few ACME products listed in the old 1900's-era Sears catalogs etc:   https://farm8.static.flickr.com/7748/26861261164_858c0b1b60_b.jpg

Comment: @SztupY We don't actually know that. The dehydrated boulders only have "Acme" on the side of the packet, and we can't see the side of the jet shoe box.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - The Jim Dandy box has an acme logo on the side

Comment: @SztupY This article http://mentalfloss.com/article/567190/gigantic-poster-features-every-product-fictional-acme-corporation-ever-produced says Fleet-Foot is a sub-brand of Acme. No clue where they got that from though.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

### Road Runner brands

In [*Fast and Furry-ous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_and_Furry-ous) (1949) Wile E. Coyote uses an "**Ace**" brand electric motor.

[image: gray box labelled "Ace Electric Motor"]

and "***Fleet-Foot***" jet-propelled tennis shoes.

[image: white box labelled "Fleet-Foot Jet-Propelled Tennis Shoes" with a blue shoe sitting next to it]

---

In [*Beep, Beep!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beep,_Beep_(film)) (1952) Wile E. Coyote uses an empty "**Harris Soup**" box as a stand. This, presumably was an homage to animator Ken Harris.

[image: Brown box with a glass of water sitting on top. The side of the box says "Harris Soup" in red letters and "Free Drink of Water" on the side.]

---

In [*Zipping Along*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipping_Along) (1953) we see another Ace product, steel shot.

[image: Red can labelled "Ace Steel Shot" being poured into a blue box labelled "Acme Bird Seed"]

---

In [*Ready, Set, Zoom!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready,_Set,_Zoom!) (1955), our hapless protagonist travels through a mine owned by the "**Selzer Mining Co.**", presumably an homage to producer Eddie Selzer.

[image: Yellow sign sticking up out of rubble saying "Selzer Mining Co."]

---

In [*Zoom and Bored*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoom_and_Bored) (1957) Wile E. Coyote has gotten himself an "**Ahab**" branded harpoon gun.

[image: Wile E. Coyote aiming a metallic gray harpoon gun labelled "Ahab Harpoon Gun"]

---

In [*Going! Going! Gosh!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going!_Going!_Gosh!) we find that Wile E. Coyote has bought an "**Excelsior**" branded electric fan.

[image: Open yellow box with white wrapping paper inside, labelled "Excelsior Electric Fan"]

---

In *[Rushing Roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rushing_Roulette)* (1965) we encounter "**Ajax**" brand glue.

[image: Blue rectangular can that has the words "Ajax Stix-All Glue" in blue, and underneath on a red section of the can "A real sticker"]

and what appears to be a *Greyhound* branded bus. Note that this is a [real brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greyhound_Lines), not a fictional one.

[image: Gray bus with a Greyhound logo]

---

In *[Zip 'n' Snort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%27N_Snort)* (1961) we also see another Ajax product, bird seed.

[image: Orange box labelled "Ajax Bird Seed"]

---

In [*Compressed Hare*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_Hare) (1961), Bugs Bunny orders a "**Zajaxi**" branded dynamo to use against Wile E. Coyote.

[image: A wooden box with a crowbar leaning against it. It has a white label saying "Zajaxi Dynamo"]

---

In [*Adventures of the Road Runner*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventures_of_the_Road_Runner) (1962) we see that Wile E. Coyote has foolishly been buying "**Road-Runner Blue-Print Co.**" branded blueprints.

[image: Blue paper that says in white "A product of Road-Runner Blue-Print Co. Pheonix·Taos·Santa Fe·Flagstaff and elsewhere", a white outline of a roadrunner next to the words]

---

In [*To Beep or Not to Beep*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Beep_or_Not_to_Beep) (1963) we see that the Wile E. Coyote has foolishly bought a giant (and consistently defective) catapult from the "**Road-Runner Manufacturing Co.**"

[image: Pink sign that says in blue letters "Built by the Road-Runner Manufacturing Co." "Pheonix·Taos·Santa Fe·Flagstaff" "Patent pending" "Reg. U.S. Pat. Off." and a picture of a roadrunner next to it]

---

### Looney-Tunes *co-branded* adverts

In this series of [Plymouth Cars commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jt8aeTgY9u8) (this one from 1968), we learn that Ajax also manufacture rocket cars.

[image: White sign over a brick doorway that says "Ajax Rocket Cars"]

In the [1969 commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mduTKn6Npg), we see that Ajax have diversified into 'dumping'.

[image: Brown dumptruck with "Ajax Dumping" visible on the side]

And in this [1970 commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2bRc-sNt6c), Ajax evidently sell 'car crushers' as well.

[image: Gray box with springs on the side, with the label "Ajax Car Crusher"]

---

In a [series of commercials for Energizer Batteries](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1OyKU0A7Iuh67_54mz5wyHRJy04W_SMv), Wile E. Coyote finds that their fictional rival brand "**SUPERVOLT**" are (as usual) underwhelming.

[image: Black batteries labelled "Supervolt"]

---

In the late 1960s, Warner Bros came up with the idea for a branded Road Runner cereal called "**[Post's Beep Beep Cereal](https://www.mrbreakfast.com/cereal_detail.asp?id=1366)**" and even went as far as mocking up [an animatic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLm_Jm7On9o) to show Post Cereals executives what the advert might look like. Since the brand only existed on paper (the deal wasn't finalised), this seems to fall into the category of 'fictional'.

[image: A roadrunner running past holding a box of "Post's Beep Beep Cereal"]

---

### Recent Looney Tunes brands

In *Tiny Toon Adventures*, toons have a choice of attending Acme Looniversity or its rival, "**Perfecto Prep**" as seen in [The Acme Bowl](https://tinytoons.fandom.com/wiki/The_Acme_Bowl) (1990) and other episodes.

[image: A statue visible against a night sky. The pedestal of the statue says "Perfecto Prep. Our motto "We never lose""]

### Looney Tunes brands (pre-1960)

In [*Duck Dodgers In The 24½th Century*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers_in_the_24%C2%BDth_Century) (1952) Marvin has a tendency to use "**A-1**" branded products, a brand that's also seen (occasionally) in the early Looney Tunes cartoons.

[image: A yellow gun that says "A-1 Disintegrating Pistol" , and a yellow device with three knobs sticking up labelled "A-1 Ultimatum Answerer"]

---

In [*Cheese Chasers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_Chasers) (1952) Hubie and Herbert raid a cheese factory called "**Hunka Cheese Co.**"

[image: A blue building with a clock tower, with the name "Hunka Cheese Co."]

---

In [*Mouse Wreckers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_Wreckers) (1949), Claude Cat has a green bottle of "**Harris**" hair tonic in his medicine cabinet.

[image: A medicine cabinet. Claude Cat is holding a clear bottle with purple liquid labelled "Nerve Tonic". Next to that is a green bottle labelled "Harris hair tonic".]

---

In [*Smile, Darn Ya, Smile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smile,_Darn_Ya,_Smile!) (1931) Foxy the trolley engineer has adverts on his trolley bus for "**Sniff Brothers**" cough drops and "**Risk**" Tires

[image: Gray advertisement showing a dog coughing on another dog with the label "Sniff Brothers cough drops", and a mouse holding a candle next to a tire with a nail stuck in it labelled "Risk tires".]

---

In [*The Dish Ran Away with the Spoon*](https://looneytunes.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dish_Ran_Away_with_the_Spoon) (1933), we see some "**Sunrise**" prunes in the background of the kitchen.

[image: Box of dark dried fruit labelled "Sunrise prunes", with a picture of the sun on the box.]

---

In [*Buddy's Day Out*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy%27s_Day_Out) (1933), our hero is implored to smoke "**Gazelles**" cigarettes and "**Myrol**" cigarettes.

[image: Road signs saying "Smoke Gazelles" and "Smoke Myrol Cigarettes".]

---

In [*Buddy's Beer Garden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy%27s_Beer_Garden) (1933), Buddy serves "**Bock**" beer.

[image: Poster on a brick wall saying "Bock Beer", with a picture of a goat.]

---

In [*Sittin' on a Backyard Fence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sittin%27_on_a_Backyard_Fence) (1933), the alleycats are sitting on a fence with posters that advertise two distinctive brands; "**Bull Dernem**" tobacco and "**Tarnation**" milk.

[image: Two signs. One says "Bull Dernem Tobacco" with a picture of a bull behind a wooden fence, and the other says "Tarnation milk from contented cows" with a picture of three cows.]

---

[*How Do I Know It's Sunday?*](https://looneytunes.fandom.com/wiki/How_Do_I_Know_It%27s_Sunday) (1934) features a veritable cornucopia of fake and parody brands; "**Anchor**" sardines, "**Pink Ribbon**" malt, "**American Biscuit Baking Co.**" crackers, "**Aunt Mamie**" and "**Aunt Eliza**" pancake flour, "**Scream**" wheat, "**Old Maid**" cleanser, "**Burno**" canned heat, "**Searchlight**" cleanser, "**Jamble Inc.**" cleaner, "**MB Spice Co.**" tinned peppers, "**Garo**" syrup, "**Pratts**" biscuits, "**Sunny Side**" raisins, "**Kelly's**" corn flakes, "**Best-o**" toilet paper, "**Norm's**" crackers and "**Tibby**" evaporated milk.

[image: A rectangular can of "Anchor" sardines with a dollar sign n the box, "Pink Ribbon" malt with three people visible on the label, "Unwanta crackers" by American Biscuit Baking Co.", "Aunt Mamie" and "Aunt Eliza" pancake flour, "Scream" wheat, "Old Maid" cleanser, a circular can of "Burno canned heat", "Searchlight" cleanser with a person shining a light, "Jamble Inc." cleaner, "MB Spice Co." tinned peppers, "Garo" syrup, "Pratts" biscuits, "Sunny Side" raisins, "Kelly's" corn flakes, "Best-o" toilet paper, "Norm's" crackers and "Tibby" evaporated milk.]

---

In [*Milk and Money*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_and_Money_(film)) (1936), Porky Pig works for the "**Fuller Water Milk Co.**" as a milkman.

[image: Sign over a doorway that says "Fuller-Water Milk Co."]

---

In [*Wholly Smoke*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wholly_Smoke) (1938) Porky Pig encounters a range of cigarette brands; "**El Ropo**" cigars, "**Union**" tobacco, "**Barkley Square**" tobacco, "**Picadilly Sprouts**" cheroots, "**Velour**" smoking tobacco and "**The Hibernian Tobacco Co.**", makers of 'Genuine Bossy Flakes'.

[image: "El Ropo" cigars, "Union" tobacco, "Barkley Square" tobacco, "Picadilly Sprouts" cheroots, "Velour" smoking tobacco with smoke coming out of a pipe, and "The Hibernian Tobacco Co. Genuine Bossy Flakes" with a large pig visible.]

---

In [*You're An Education*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You%27re_an_Education) (1938),we learn that travellers can travel via a boat from the "**Alaska Steamship Company**"

[image: Map of the ocean with a section in red on the bottom, saying "Alaska Steamship Company "The Alaska Line""]

---

In [*The Night-Watchman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_Watchman_(1938_film)) (1938), Tommy Cat walks past another A-1 product, a box of pretzels.

[image: White box that says "A-1 Pretzels" in orange text.]

---

In *[The Sour Puss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sour_Puss)* (1940) we see another company name, "**Consolidated Pants**". Interestingly, this is also the first mention of "**Acme**" as a company name.

[image: Newspaper headline saying "Acme suspenders break: Consolidated pants drop!" Three sections below that say "Shareholder shoots self-...", "Wall street at a glance", and "Crash follows sharp rally"]

---

In [*Tortoise Beats Hare*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortoise_Beats_Hare), Cecil Turtle uses a "**Bell Turtlephone Co.**" branded telephone box to call his family.

[image: A white sign with a blue picture of a bell that says "turtle system" on it, with the text "Bell Turtlephone Co." circling the bell.]

---

In [*Goofy Groceries*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goofy_Groceries) (1941) we see another slew of fake and parody product names and company names; "**Jelly Bean Co.**" jelly beans, "**Speeds**" premium hams, "**Guavida Rock Co.**", "**Star Products**", "**Sid's**" mustard, "**Fountain Spray Candy Co.**", "**Weate Company**", "**Uama Biscuit Co.**", "**Superguy Co.**" soap chips.

[image: A blue package of "Jelly Bean Co." jelly beans, a white bag of "Speeds" premium hams with a yellow logo, a red sign saying "Manufactured by the only Guavida Rock Co.", a package of "Star Products Malbi Toast", a bottle of yellow "Sid's" mustard, "Fountain Spray Candy Co.", "Weate Company", "Uama Biscuit Co.", and "Superguy Co." soap chips with an image of a superhero]

---

In [*The Wabbit Who Came to Supper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wabbit_Who_Came_to_Supper) (1942), Elmer receives a telegram courtesy of "**Eastern Union**", an obvious parody of Western Union

[image: A telegram with the header "Eastern Union", with the text "HD800 26 LOSANGELES CALIF ...-1069 CHEEVER AVENUE" visible underneath.]

---

In [*Baseball Bugs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball_Bugs) (1946) we see a couple of brands; "**Ross Co.**" shoes and a "**Mellow Cab Company**" taxi.

[image: Billboard with a sign for "Lausbub's bread" and "Ross Co." shoes, and a yellow vehicle with the words "Mellow Cab Company".]

---

In [*Rabbit Transit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_Transit_(film)) (1947) we see another telegram company; "**Western Bunions**", another obvious parody of Western Union.

[image: Telegram with the heading "Western Bunions".]

---

In [*Slick Hare*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slick_Hare) (1947), Bug Bunny eats carrots grown by the "**Takaimotto Brothers, Inc.**"

[image: Blue sign with the words "Imperial Valley growers CARROTS Superfine extras Takaimotto Brothers, Inc]

---

In [*Bugs Bunny Rides Again*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugs_Bunny_Rides_Again) (1948) we see another taxi company; "**Yellow Coach Co.**"

[image: Bugs Bunny in a yellow vehicle that says "Yellow Coach Co." on top and "Taxi" on the bottom.]

Comment: I am simply amazed. The question was asked yesterday at 21:30. Your full answer was done about 12 hours later, **including a night**. Out of curiosity: how can someone be so knowledgeable about cartoon (and TV details, in general) to dig these up? I answer technical questions and these are easy: if I know the answer, it is a matter of sourcing it correctly, but the sources are usually limited (documentation) and I know where to look for them. Or I have an opinion and it is even simpler. Here you had to dig into cartoons! Knowing which to ding into! Incredible.

Comment: @WoJ - [Connor Ratliff's twitter feed](https://twitter.com/connorratliff/status/940658056148537344?lang=en-gb) was an enormous help, as was the [Wile E. Coyote and the Road Runnerr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wile_E._Coyote_and_the_Road_Runner) which mentions a variety of other brands and (helpfully) the episodes in which they're found. I also watched about 40 episodes (at 48x speed) to see if I'd missed anything.

Comment: Now the question is - has Valorum _missed_ any non-Acme branded products?